Questions on isomorphism of graphs
According to the following document : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_labeling, the set of vertices(abstract mathematical object) of a graph and the set of the labels(integers, characters, etc.) of vertices are different.

Since vertices and labels are different, should I treat vertices without labels as indistinguishable objects? If not, how can we distinguish them without labels?

Here is the definition of isomorphism of graph: G = (V , E) and G′ = (V′ , E′) are called isomorphic if a bijection f : V → V′ exists such that {x,y}∈E if and only if {f(x), f(y)}∈E’ holds for all x,y ∈ V , x != y. Such an f is called an isomorphism of the graphs G and G′. While the definition seems to consider the set of vertices instead of labels, I’m confused because many textbook and internet examples express graph isomorphism as a map from labels to labels just like the below picture from Wikipedia.

I think testing isomorphism between two graphs can be done by just checking their connectivity without the use of labels. However, the definition of isomorphism as a map between two sets forces me to think that elements in each set need to be distinguishable by some use of label. Otherwise, how do we express which one is being mapped to which?
I wonder if graph isomorphism is just vertex relabeling(which makes the use of label essential when dealing with isomorphism). If not, how should I understand isomorphism as a bijection between indistinguishable vertices, not just a relationship in which two graphs have the same connectivity?

If labels are useless in isomorphism and vertices are indistinguishable, why do we need automorphism, an isomorphism in which the domain and codomain of vertices are the same? Shouldn’t automorphism just create the same graph?


In a nutshell, do I have to think vertices and labels separately? If I have to, how do I detach the two concepts from each other in terms of mappings between graphs such as graph isomorphism.

Without labels, we have no way to describe or define the isomorphism in language or symbols.

In formal mathematics, any two distinct elements in a set have different "names". In an unlabelled graph, these names are structurally "unimportant". Some thoughts:

When two graphs $G,H$ are isomorphic, we think of them as "the same" $G\cong H$. If all the vertices have the same names, then they are "equal" $G=H$. If they are unlabelled, an isomorphism between $G$ and $H$ basically renames the vertices to make them equal. We don’t care about the names, so we can change them via isomorphism.
Suppose $G$ and $H$ are labelled graph with labels in $L$. That is, for all $v\in V(G),V(H)$, there is some label $\ell(v)\in L$. By distinguishing between vertices like this, there is a new definition. $G$ and $H$ are now only isomorphic (in the labelled sense) if there is a bijection $f:V(G)\to V(H)$ so that edges are preserved, and also for all $v\in V(G)$, we must have $\ell(v)=\ell(f(v))$ (the labels cannot change).
An automorphism on $G$ is a way of renaming vertices so the resulting graph is "equal" to the original. For example, if $u$ and $v$ have the same adjacencies in $G$, then swapping $u$ with $v$ is an automorphism. Of course, any renaming of $V(G)$ is isomorphic to $G$, but not necessarily equal.
Isomorphism testing cannot be done with just connectivity. In fact, for any graph property you can think of, it is not enough to check isomorphism (degree sequence, chromatic number, clique sizes,...) . As far as I know, the only general way is to find a bijection.
Think of vertices as having "forgettable names" that you can exchange via isomorphism, and usually rename however you wish. Labels, on the other hand, are fixed and must be preserved under isomorphism.

